# Drawing a horizontal line in a DataGridView Cell

Tags: c#, winforms

this is my panel1 paint event

```css
Pen graphPen = new Pen(Color.White, 10);
PointF pt1D = new PointF();
PointF pt2D = new PointF();
pt1D.X = 5;
pt1D.Y = 10;
pt2D.X = 175;
pt2D.Y = 10;

e.Graphics.DrawLine(graphPen, pt1D, pt2D);
e.Graphics.DrawLine(graphPen, 5, 10, 175, 10);
```

help me same method on datagridview cell paint event apply.
i want drawing drawline on datagridview cell

Answer (score 1):

this is not good for real application, but if you **Have TO** do this, you can use this

```
//subscribing the event
dataGridView1.CellPainting += dataGridView1_CellPainting;

//handle the event
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top+e.CellBounds.Height / 2, e.CellBounds.Right,e.CellBounds.Top+ e.CellBounds.Height / 2);

        e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

and the result is same as this:

[image]

But, As I told before, don't use this to real application

Comment: k,thanks,but actuallu i want if i double click on any cell it shold be shown filed rectangle color again i double click its hide.this is what i want.