# Draw red line inside datagridview cells

Tags: c#, datagridview

[image]

how can I add red line into cell?

```
    private void dataGridView_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        var dg = (DataGridView)sender;

        if (e.ColumnIndex == -5 || e.RowIndex != (dg.RowCount -1))
            return;

        using (var p = new Pen(Color.Red, 1))
        {
            var cellBounds = e.CellBounds;

            const int size = 2;
            var pts = new List<Point>();
            var h = false;
            for (int i = cellBounds.Left; i <= cellBounds.Right; i += size, h = !h)
            {
                pts.Add(
                    new Point
                    {
                        X = i,
                        Y = h ? cellBounds.Bottom : cellBounds.Bottom + size
                    });
            }

            e.Graphics.DrawLines(p, pts.ToArray());
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
       dataGridView.CellPainting += dataGridView_CellPainting;
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell us where in the code you are having and or experiencing an issue.. please also read about how to ask a question.. I would also like to know if you have actually used the debugger and stepped through the code by setting breakpoints.. and pinpointing which line(s) are causing the problem do a simple google search there are actually tons of working example on how to do this here is one here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26120268/drawing-a-horizontal-line-in-a-datagridview-cell

Comment: You should not add the `dataGridView_CellPainting` event handler in every `dataGridView_Paint` call! But only once, maybe in the Form constructor or better yet, simply in the designer!

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

- All those Points you create really make no sense at all. To draw a line you only need two points and for a series of n lines a series n+1 points.
- Do not add more and more handlers for `CellPainting`! Each call of `dataGridView_Paint` adds one more. All this should be deleted. Add the handler in the designer!
- The `CellPainting` event has a few rules to follow:

  - If you handle the drawing you need to handle **all** of it, including drawing the background and the content
  - To make your life (a lot) easier there are ready calls for this, right in the param `e`
  - If you want to handle the drawing you need to abort the system drawing by setting `e.Handled = true;`

Here is code that draws a red line under each cell, including the `RowHeader`:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    var dg = (DataGridView)sender;  // a short reference
    if (e.ColumnIndex == -5 || e.RowIndex != (dg.RowCount - 1))
        return;

    using (var p = new Pen(Color.Red, 1))
    {
        var cb = e.CellBounds;  // a short reference

        e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);
        e.PaintContent(e.ClipBounds);
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(p, cb.X, cb.Y + cb.Height, cb.X + cb.Width, cb.Y + cb.Height);

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

I left it in, but I wonder what `e.ColumnIndex == -5` is meant to do; maybe a typo? To exclude the `RowHeader` change it to `e.ColumnIndex < 0` or else leave it out!